# How to combine to shapes into one? Sketch

Tags: sketch-3

I have just installed sketch and I am trying to create a circle with a tick sign inside. 
The issue is that whenever I use the Union option to merge the circle and tick sign the tick sign is hidden. Here are the steps.

1. Insert -> Shape -> Oval
2. Insert -> Vector
3. I draw the tick sign
4. Select all layers specified above and click on union.
5. Tick sign is no longer shown inside the circle.

[image: before union]
[image: after union]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union creates a newer shape with the outer boundaries of the elements. In your case, the check mark is inside the circle and the result is just the circle. The right operation would be: 
1 convert the check mark into an outline (Shift + Cmd + O) 
2 select the circle and the checkmark
3 use the option subtract so the new shape would be the circle minus the checkmark.

[image: Combined Shape with Subtract]

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question which is, how to arrive at this final visual result with only one shape. Here there are two. Not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can select both and create a symbol. Then export the symbol. You don't need union for this since you don't have any of the two shapes protruding outside the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Group the two layers in step 4, rather than Union. Wouldn't that accomplish what you're looking to do?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).